# raisecallbackevent not fired on safari 7.1

Tags: .net, icallbackeventhandler

I am using ICallbackEventHandler throughout my website to handle callbacks.
After Updating Safari to version 7.1 on MAC 10.9.5 its not working at all.

In all other browser its working fine.

Any kind of help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Can't help with your specific issue, but for what it's worth, I've hit several major issues with Safari V7.1 on Mac.  The mousewheel event only fires at the start of scroll. If you bind parameters to a function invoked by setTimeout(...) they intermittently contain garbage. A version to be avoided!